# lambda with non final variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know that you can't have non final/effective final variable inside the lambda. if this happen there may be case you are working on outdated version of the object. I figured that the compiler didn't complain about this code where the function parameter may not be final :

**Updating the post with full code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object x=new Object();
    x=new Object();// I can reassign x as much as I can
    test(x);
}


  public static void test(Object x) {
// I can't reassign x here, shouldn't it disallow me to use function parameter ?
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(entry->System.out.println(entry+x)); // x here could be not final why the compiler didn't complain ?
}
```

Comment: Because it's effectively final. Do you assign any value to `x` inside the method? No. So it's effectively final.

Comment: It is *effectively final*

Comment: What's `Object x`? You can `+` object

Comment: @JBNizet but I do outside. why it doesn't allow me inside but outside it does

Comment: @MohammadKarmi - You don't anywhere in the code in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated the post

Comment: The variable `x` of the main method is not the same variable `x` as in the test method. They just happen to have the same name, but they're defined in separate scopes. One is a local variable of main(), the other is a local variable of test(). The one in test() is never assigned, so it's effectively final.

Comment: @MohammadKarmi - Re your edit: Assigning to `x` in `main` has no effect whatsoever on he `x` in `test`. One is a local variable, the other is a method parameter. Other than that the variables' **value** is passed to the method, there is no connection between them whatsoever.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not sure how did I miss this :) you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in your question: Because `x` in `test` is *effectively final*, because nothing in `test` assigns to it.

Note that `x` in `test` and `x` in `main` have no connection to each other whatsoever. At one point in main, you do read the value of `main`'s `x` and pass that value into `test`, but it's the **value** that's passed, not some kind of connection or link to the `x` variable itself. (Java is a purely [pass-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) language.) There is no ongoing connection between the two `x`s. They just happen to both contain the same value (an object reference). The fact you can assign to `main`'s `x` has no bearing on whether you can assign to `test`'s `x`.

Comment: what happens to `x` inside `test` method after the method is terminated ? local variables should be deleted but in cases of anonymous class it should still be there right ? as it would be used later

Comment: @MohammadKarmi - No, the parameter or variable (I'll just say "variable" for simplicity) goes away regardless. That's part of why only final or effectively-final variables can be used in anonymous classes and lambdas, to avoid confusion: It's not really the variable that's being used, it's a *copy* of the variable's value. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943134/157247). This isn't really relevant to your question, since the lambda doesn't survive the termination of the method anyway, but if it did, the `x` parameter would still go away, and the lambda would keep a copy of its value.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is effectively final.  A variable or parameter whose value is never changed after it is initialized is effectively final.